# Back button not rendering

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

I have an overlay that I want to slide in my cocoa-touch application. I have created the view controller for it and the corresponding nib. The nib just has a View with a text field in it.

I move to the view using:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[[[AddPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddPlayerViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease] animated: YES];
```

This works fine and the view slides in. However, the back/cancel button doesn't render. I can click there and it goes back, but nothing is drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought, does the first view have a title? Try setting it if not...

Comment: what the heck?

that's awesome.